Default SLD symbology broken in Kartoza's GeoServer docker-compose
I successfully ran a dockerized instance of GeoServer, using docker compose and the Kartoza images.
The problem is that the default SLD styles seems to be broken.
The validation of the SLD gives me this error:
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Entity resolution disallowed for null
If I apply one of this styles to a layer, I get this as a result of the layer preview:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://127.0.0.1/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
      java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableExceptionorg.xml.sax.SAXException: Entity resolution disallowed for null
Entity resolution disallowed for null
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>

You can check this screenshot.

What should I do to fix this?
The logs can be accessed here: https://pastebin.com/r1sW2qyk

can you add the full stack trace from the log file

Sure @IanTurton: https://pastebin.com/r1sW2qyk

I had the same error, and as others pointed out, it seems it was a bug in kartoza's Docker image. I upgraded to 2.25.1, which was recently released and the issue was fixed.

The error seems to be
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Entity resolution disallowed for null

The default point style does not have any references to external entities and I do not get any errors with GeoServer that I installed from the zip file. Maybe the docker file does not use the default settings which are documented in https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/production/config.html#external-entities-resolution
That theory could be tested by activating the unrestricted entity resolution from the global settings.

If the default point style works then the question is why the Kartoza image denies access to Null or nothing and how to workaround it.

Thanks for this answer. It helped point me in the right direction. It looks like this has been fixed at the kartoza-geoserver repo: https://github.com/kartoza/docker-geoserver/commit/5bafd395b4ea02ad9fdb53abec487bef7c1261e3

Look's like kartoza docker bug. I rolled back 2.25.0 to 2.23.2 and it works now.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks, will try.
